# Android Kotlin - Unresolved reference: AppCompatActivity after updating to 1.5

Tags: android, kotlin, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

After the update to

```
'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
```

I get unresolved reference

in

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
```

at

`AppCompatActivity()`

I deleted the old imports which were marked red to see if there will be import suggestions on hover over AppCompatActivity but there is nothing.

I also cleared and rebuilt the project.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to older Android Studio version, I didn't get an update notification because there was an issue with the kotlin version.

I uninstalled/reinstalled kotlin plugin, updated Android Studio and then everything worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case, neither the `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` class nor the `androidx.appcompat.app` package could be resolved because I did not have an explicit dependency in my application's `build.gradle` file on the `appcompat` library.

My application was able to resolve the `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` class previously because one or more of the AndroidX libraries that I was depending on had an explicit dependency on the `appcompat` library.

However, it seems that recent versions of the AndroidX libraries hide away their dependency on the `appcompat` library so it's necessary for us to make an explicit `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` dependency declaration in our applications.